# Limit of sequence of irrational function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Are there any conditions or theorem to the limit of a sequence of irrational functions is irrational ? Please say something i don't know , because I already know sequences of examples of irrational functions whose limit is rational.Maybe if there is uniform convergence ...

Comment: Probably you mean irrational *numbers* instead of irrational functions?  Maybe it's not what you're looking for, but there are some results about the irrationality of limits of sequences of *rational* numbers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no condition on the rate of convergence or the uniformity that can guarantee a sequence of irrational real functions converges to an irrational function.  For instance, pick your favorite real polynomial $p(x)$ and consider the functions $$g_n(x)=e^{-nx^2}p(x). $$  This sequence of transcendental functions converges ultra-super fast and uniformly to $p(x)$, but $p(x)$ is rational.

There are other criteria of irrationality, for instance a sequence of irrational functions whose zero sets become dense in the line cannot converge uniformly to a rational function, but this involves notions beyond the rate and nature of convergence.

Generally, if your functions do not behave like rational functions near the limit (grow or decay exponentially at infinity, accumulate zeros and so on) they will not have a rational uniform limit (this is even more spectacular when we are considering irrational meromorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}$ becaue rational functions are characterized as those functions meromorphic at infninity).  But none of these things can be inferred from the rate or uniformity of convergence alone in the real case as the example I gave shows.